# Nil element of array in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I've got image processing script in Ruby. I want to take all the pixels in an array, and then do the script in which I will change random pixels to make the image noise. But when I getting this pixels I have got a nil error. Here is my code.

```
require 'mini_magick'
first_image  = MiniMagick::Image.new("123.png")
a = 0
b = 0

pixels = first_image.get_pixels
loop do
  print "\n"
  a=a+1
  while pixels[a][b] != nil do
    print pixels[a][b].to_s + "\n"
    b+=1
  end
  b = 0
  break if pixels[a][b] == nil
end
```

And this is what I am receiving in a terminal:

```
Imagenoise.rb:10:in `block in <main>': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from Imagenoise.rb:7:in `loop'
    from Imagenoise.rb:7:in `<main>'
```

Comment: what is the output for `first_image.pixels`?

Comment: It's a method of the gem minimagick (according to https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick) in which I can retrieve a matrix of image pixels, where each member of the matrix is a 3-element array of numbers between 0-255, one for each range of the RGB color channels.

Comment: And for that loop, where I am printing each element of that two dimension array pixels[height][wifth], I have got that output `[24, 30, 28]
[29, 36, 29]
[107, 118, 102]
[175, 189, 166]`

Comment: Your code is missing a break if `pixels[a]` returns `nil`. That happens when `a` is bigger than the number of pixels in the image.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't check if you reached the end of the image. Therefore `pixels[a]` returns `nil` at some point (once `a` is bigger than the number of pixels in the image) and `pixel[a][b]` fails because you cannot call `nil[b]`.

You can avoid situations like that by not iterating manually through the array and instead use `each` blocks:

```
require 'mini_magick'

image  = MiniMagick::Image.new('123.png')
pixels = image.get_pixels

pixels.each do |pixel|
  pixel.each do |color|
    puts color
  end
end
```

Comment: Yup, this is it ! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

It is throwing error because `pixels[a]` is nil and thus `pixels[a][b]` is in error. You can do something like this to prevent error.

```
while pixels[a] != nil do
  print pixels[a][b].to_s + "\n"
  b+=1
end
```